# Как правильно прекратить выполнение go программы?

Tags: golang

код - hello world на 127.0.0.1:8080 через http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil).
Компилирую, запускаю в терминале (Ubuntu 14.04). Захожу браузером - все нормально. 
Прерываю выполнение в терминале, меняю код, компилирую, выполняю - пишет: 
ListenAndServe: listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use. 
Если закрыть/открыть терминал - все работает.
Как  можно работать в одном окне терминала, не закрывая его?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте таймаут вместо nil http://habrahabr.ru/post/197468/

Answer (score 0):

Используй лучше go run <имя программы>